# Room, Boolean and kotlin interface lead to ambiguous getter error

Tags: kotlin, android-room

Having following interface and class:

```
interface IUserCreated {
    val userCreated: Boolean
}

@Entity
data class Test(

        @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "test_id") var id: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_created") override val userCreated: Boolean

) : IUserCreated
```

This leads to following error:

```
error: Ambiguous getter for Field(element=userCreated, name=userCreated, type=boolean, affinity=INTEGER, collate=null, columnName=user_created, defaultValue=null, parent=null, indexed=false, nonNull=true). 
All of the following match: getUserCreated, isUserCreated. You can @Ignore the ones that you don't want to match.
```

**Question**

How can I use the `@Ignore` annotation in this example? The `userCreated` boolean field is part of the entity, I just want to ignore the unused `getUserCreated` and tell room that it should use the default kotlin getter function `isUserCreated`

**Note**

I know I can solve this by doing following:

```
interface IUserCreated {
    val internalUserCreated: Boolean
    fun getUserCreated(): Boolean = internalUserCreated
}

@Entity
data class Test(

        @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "test_id") var id: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_created") override val internalUserCreated: Boolean

) : IUserCreated
```

I wonder if I can somehow solve this without the workaround, I don't want to do this for every boolean field in any entity I use, but I don't know how I can use the `@Ignore` annotation to fix the problem.